# Clio OAuth2 Screen Mobile Friendly Version? Doing something wrong?

Tags: clio-api

we're authorizing Clio via OAuth2 and the web flow is great, on a desktop, but out of iOS the screen doesn't seem very mobile friendly. We're redirecting to Mobile Safari (e.g. external url launch in true safari, *NOT* an embedded WKWebView/UIWebView/whatever), and we still see issues with scrolling to see the full page and access the buttons in portrait on iPhone sized devices. Moving it to landscape works around the issue but it's still not very mobile friendly at all, in portrait, no matter how much you swipe & scroll you simply *cannot* get to the list of permissions asked and the allow/deny buttons.

Again, we're redirecting straight out to the authorization url in full safari. Is there a parameter we can set to ask Clio to present a mobile-friendly view, perhaps?

See attached video for an example, trust me, I'm swiping all ways to try to make it work in portrait. I worry about this because even if there's a workaround, it's not obvious and the user experience here isn't intuitive (most of our users would not think to rotate the device).

Thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzler7u31jvknzo/ScreenRecording_07-28-2018%2016-18-34.m4v?dl=0

---

Answer (score 0):

This is Matt G. from Clio's API support team.

There currently isn't the ability to set the Authorization page to a mobile friendly view. While we're tracking interest in this improvement, work for adding this functionality isn't currently on our roadmap.

We'll reach out directly when we can provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

The Clio API V4 application authorization page   has been updated to provide a view for mobile devices when detected.

This authorization page is presented to the user when an app is initially connected to the Clio API / data source.